# If $A_1 \subset A_2 \subset \mathbb R$ and $m^*(A_1) = m^*(A_2)$, will $m^*(A_1 \cap T) = m^*(A_2 \cap T), \forall T \subset \mathbb R$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

> Definition of **Lebesgue Outer Measure**: Given a set $E$ of $\mathbb R$, we define the **Lebesgue Outer Measure** of $E$ by, $$m^*(E) = \inf \left\{\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} l(I_n): E \subset \bigcup_{n=1}^{+\infty}I_n \right\}$$ where $l(I_n)$ denotes the length of interval (bounded and nonempty interval).
>
> Definition of **measurable set**: A set $E$ measurable if $$m^*(T) = m^*(T \cap E) + m^*(T \cap E^c)$$ for every subset of $T$ of $\mathbb R$.
>
> If $A_1 \subset A_2 \subset \mathbb R$ and $m^*(A_1) = m^*(A_2)$, will $$m^*(A_1 \cap T) = m^*(A_2 \cap T)$$ for all $T \subset \mathbb R$? Why? How about the result if $A_1$ being a measurable set added?

Update:

Sincerely, I appreciate user140776's answer and he gives the counterexample that equality doesn't hold for $m^*(A_1) = m^*(A_2) = +\infty$. I still have a question: if $m^*(A_1) = m^*(A_2) < +\infty$, does the equality hold? Or it doesn't hold until adding the condition that $A_1$ is measurable?

Besides, if I remove the restriction of $A_1$ being a subset of $A_2$ that is $A_1, A_2 \subset \mathbb R$ and $m^*(A_1) = m^*(A_2) < +\infty$, will that equality $$m^*(A_1 \cap T) = m^*(A_2 \cap T)$$ for all $T \subset \mathbb R$ still hold?

Comment: If $A_1$ is measurable then, $m^*(A_2\cap T)=m^*(A_2\cap T\cap A_1)+m^*(A_2\backslash A_1\cap T)$ and since $A_2$ and $A_1$ differ by a set of measure zero, the second term on the right hand side is 0, and since $A_1\subset A_2$, the first term on the right hand side is $m^*(A_1\cap T)$

Comment: @user140776: Ohhh, yes. make sense. How do you think if A1 being a measurable set is removed?

Comment: I don't know. I'm still learning. The only thing I can say about that is that, we certainly know that $m^*(A_1\cap T)\le m^*(A_2\cap T)$ because $A_1\cap T\subset A_2\cap T$. So the question is whether it is possible to find $A_1, A_2, T$ satisfying the conditions such that $m^*(A_1\cap T)<m^*(A_2\cap T)$.

Comment: @user140776: Yes. I hold the same question as you have. I'm not sure whether some nonmeasurable set T will make $m^*(A_1 \cap T) < m^*(A_2 \cap T)$ work.

Comment: @user140776 You don't need that $A_1$ is measurable. For your argument you just used that the outer measure is additive for disjoint sets and that the subsets of a null set are null sets too.

Comment: @user251257: No.  outer measure is subadditive for disjoint sets. There exists a sequence of pairwise disjoint subsets $\{E_n\}$ of [0,1) with $m^*(\bigcup_{n=1}^{+\infty} E_n) < \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} m^*(E_n)$.

Comment: oh, you are right. no idea, what I have thought of.

Comment: But here you have $m^*(A_1\cap T) \le m^*(A_2\cap T) \le m^*(A_1\cap A_2\cap T) + 0$. No additivity are needed.

Comment: @user251257 Good point. Maybe you should make that an answer rather than a comment.

Comment: hm, I am not sure that $m^*(A_2\setminus A_1) = 0$.

Comment: @user251257 Thanks for pointing that out. If $A_1$ and $A_2$ are unbounded, its easy to find counterexamples.

Answer (score 4):

I think the answer is no.

Counterexample: Let $A_1=(1,\infty)$, $A_2=(0,\infty)$ and $T=(0,1)$. Then $A_1\subset A_2\subset \mathbb{R}$, $m^*(A_2)=m^*(A_1)=\infty$ and $A_1$ is measurable. However, $m^*(A_1\cap T)=0 \ne 1=m^*(A_2 \cap T)$.

However, if *in addition* to $A_1$ being measurable, you also assume that $m^*(A_1)<\infty$, then I think maybe the result will follow from the Caratheodory condition, but I'm not 100% sure.

Comment: I agree with your answer and will upvote it. I've updated the problem to a finite condition and left it open for a proof or counterexample of equality without adding the measurable set $A_1$.

Comment: Could I ask, what is the source of this problem?

Comment: Actually, there is no source of this problem. The problem first came out to my mind when I was reading Caratheodory's definition of a measurable set that is  $m^∗(T) = m^∗(T \bigcap E)+m∗(T \bigcap E^c)$. Initially, I didn't restrict the $A_1$ being necessarily a subset of $A_2$ and it is false obviously coz outer measure is a measure of length and can't tell you the position where the set is. And then I restrict $A_1$ to a subset of $A_2$.

Comment: And then I asked my friend and he had no idea neither. But he pointed out that my initial thinking might be correct that is "If $A_1, A_2⊂ \mathbb R$ and $m^∗(A_1)=m^∗(A_2)$, will $m^∗(A_1∩T)=m^∗(A_2∩T),∀T⊂R?$". So I post a restricted one first. I will update it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a strong counterexample: For every $X \subseteq [0, 1]$, there is a $Y \subseteq X$ such that $\mu^{\star}(X) = \mu^{\star}(Y) = \mu^{\star}(X \setminus Y)$. So letting $A_1 = Y, A_2 = X, T = X \setminus Y$ gives you a strong counterexample. For our purpose, it is enough to take $A_2 = [0, 1]$ and $A_1$ to be a Bernstein subset of $[0, 1]$ (which means that both $A_1, [0, 1] \setminus A_1$ meet every perfect subset of $[0, 1]$).

Comment: I google Bernstein set and wikipedia tells me that a Bernstein set is a subset of the real line that meets every uncountable closed subset of the real line but that contains none of them. This set is so abstract to judge whether or not being a measurable set itself.

Comment: I can't understand what your example mean. Can you tell me more about it？ I'm very interested in. Thanks.